# How to use enums in C++

Tags: c++, enums

Suppose we have an `enum` like the following:

```
enum Days {Saturday, Sunday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday, Friday};
```

I want to create an instance of this `enum` and initialize it with a proper value, so I do:

```
Days day = Days.Saturday;
```

Now I want to check my variable or instance with an existing `enum` value, so I do:

```
if (day == Days.Saturday)
{
    std::cout << "Ok its Saturday";
}
```

Which gives me a compilation error:

> error: expected primary-expression before ‘.’ token

So to be clear, what is the difference between saying:

```
if (day == Days.Saturday) // Causes compilation error
```

and

```
if (day == Saturday)
```

?

What do these two actually refer to, in that one is OK and one causes a compilation error?

Comment: i know, i want o know why its giving me the error!

Comment: Its Wednesday here. You have too lot of syntax errors for C++ compiler. Starting from 'Enum'.

Comment: @Hossein, Because enums aren't the same syntax (and semantics) in both languages. The first thing I do after getting an error when trying to use a feature in a new language is look up the syntax (or if it's possible) in that language.

Comment: @chris:I know , i do the same exact thing.hopefully i got my answer.I also updated the question to be more clearer.Thank you by the way;)

Comment: "*as far as i know the enums declaration and usage in these two languages are the same.*". There's your problem, right there. C# is **not** the same language as C++. Particularly, they have different syntax for enums.

Comment: @chris - if everybody would use google or other meaning to salve their problems there would be no StackOverflow.

Comment: @chris - here on stack overflow it is MUCH more appreciated when you post a REAL answer to the question than a mean (and cheap) comment.

Answer (score 399, accepted):

This code is wrong:

```
enum Days {Saturday, Sunday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday, Friday};
Days day = Days.Saturday;
if (day == Days.Saturday)
```

Because `Days` is not a scope, nor object. It is a type. And Types themselves don't have members. What you wrote is the equivalent to `std::string.clear`.  `std::string` is a type, so you can't use `.` on it.  You use `.` on an *instance* of a class.

Unfortunately, enums are magical and so the analogy stops there.  Because with a class, you can do `std::string::clear` to get a pointer to the member function, but in C++03, `Days::Sunday` is invalid.  (Which is sad).  This is because C++ is (somewhat) backwards compatable with C, and C had no namespaces, so enumerations had to be in the global namespace.  So the syntax is simply:

```
enum Days {Saturday, Sunday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday, Friday};
Days day = Saturday;
if (day == Saturday)
```

Fortunately, [Mike Seymour](https://stackoverflow.com/users/204847/mike-seymour) observes that this has been addressed in C++11. Change `enum` to `enum class` and it gets its own scope; so `Days::Sunday` is not only valid, but is the *only* way to access `Sunday`. Happy days!

Comment: Fortunately, your complaint has been addressed in C++11. Change `enum` to `enum class` and it gets its own scope; so `Days::Sunday` is not only valid, but is the only way to access `Sunday`. Happy days!

Comment: Gotta love the C++ error messages...they prove that the language is to cumbersome to even give good feedback. I take it a 'primary-expression' is an object or a scope or some other thing that is NOT a type. Perhaps a Type is a 'secondary-expression'. And what a C++ developer might call a 'dot operator' the C++ compiler can only call a 'token'.  When it gets that hard to understand the error messages there is something wrong with the language I think.

Comment: @Travis: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/expressions#Primary_expressions. A primary expression is just the first thing in an expression, usually a name or variable or a literal.  As for the second part, I don't see a big difference between `'.' token` and `dot operator`, other than it's a token and not an operator, and it shows the exact symbol, rather than a name.

Comment: @Mike Seymour I've tried to access the enums without the scope resolution operators on a bunch of compilers, and it seems to work. You said as of C++11 it's the only way, for some reason I can just access the enum values as globals, don't need the ::

Comment: @TitoneMaurice: If you have an `enum`, you can use no scope, or the global scope (`::Saturday`).  If you have an `enum class` (which is a very different thing), then you _have_ to use `Days::Saturday`.

Comment: As of C++11 (I believe), you can now use the scope operator on regular enums too even though it isn't actually doing anything extra for you. Ex: `enum Days { Saturday, Sunday, etc}` then use `Days::Saturday`, which is identical to just using `Saturday` since it's a regular enum. I think they did this to maintain the new scoped look (used on `enum class`es) for regular `enum`s too.

Comment: You can use namespace also: namespace X { enum Y {  A, B } }... Then you can use this as follows: if (enumMember == X::A) ...  Hope it helps :-)

Answer (score 27):

Much of this should give you compilation errors.

```
// note the lower case enum keyword
enum Days { Saturday, Sunday, Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday, Friday };
```

Now, `Saturday`, `Sunday`, etc. can be used as top-level bare constants,and `Days` can be used as a type:

```
Days day = Saturday;   // Days.Saturday is an error
```

And similarly later, to test:

```
if (day == Saturday)
    // ...
```

These `enum` values are like bare constants - they're *un*-scoped - with a little extra help from the compiler: (unless you're using C++11 *enum classes*) they *aren't* encapsulated like object or structure members for instance, and you can't refer to them as *members* of `Days`.

You'll have what you're looking for with [C++11](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B11#Strongly_typed_enumerations), which introduces an `enum class`:

```
enum class Days
{
    SUNDAY,
    MONDAY,
    // ... etc.
}

// ...

if (day == Days::SUNDAY)
    // ...
```

Note that this C++ is a little different from C in a couple of ways, one is that C requires the use of the `enum` keyword when declaring a variable:

```
// day declaration in C:
enum Days day = Saturday;
```

Comment: I have updated the question,I think its now clearer what i'm exactly after:) 
By the way thankyou:)

Answer (score 26):

This will be sufficient to declare your enum variable and compare it:

```
enum Days {Saturday, Sunday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday, Friday};
Days day = Saturday;
if (day == Saturday) {
    std::cout << "Ok its Saturday";
}
```

Comment: why is it wrong to say
if ( day== Days.Satudday) ? 
they must be the same,so why is compiler complaining about it?

Comment: @Hossein the values declared in your enum do not behave like class or struct member variables. This is not the correct syntax to use

Comment: @Hossein: because `Days` is not a scope, nor object. It is a type.  And Types _themselves_ don't have members.  `std::string.clear` also fails to compile for the same reason.

Comment: @Hossein: Because that's not how enums in C++ work. Unscoped enumerations put their values into the surrounding namespace; scoped ones (`enum class`, new in 2011) have their own scope, and are accessed using the scope operator, `Days::Saturday`. The member access operator (`.`) is only used to access class members.

Comment: @MooingDUck and MikeSeymour Would one of you guys post your answer as an answer? because that is exactly what i was after by issuing this question ;)

Answer (score 19):

You can use a trick to use scopes as you wish, just declare enum in such way:

```
struct Days 
{
   enum type
   {
      Saturday,Sunday,Tuesday,Wednesday,Thursday,Friday
   };
};

Days::type day = Days::Saturday;
if (day == Days::Saturday)
```

Answer (score 13):

You are looking for ***strongly typed enumerations***, a feature available in the [C++11](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B11) standard. It turns enumerations into classes with scope values.

Using your own code example, it is:

```
  enum class Days {Saturday, Sunday, Tuesday,Wednesday, Thursday, Friday};
  Days day = Days::Saturday;

  if (day == Days::Saturday)  {
    cout << " Today is Saturday !" << endl;
  }
  //int day2 = Days::Sunday; // Error! invalid
```

Using `::` as accessors to enumerations will fail if targeting a C++ standard prior C++11. But some old compilers doesn't supported it, as well some IDEs just override this option, and set a old C++ std.

If you are using GCC, enable C+11 with **-std=c++11** or **-std=gnu11** .

Answer (score 12):

Rather than using a bunch of if-statements, enums lend themselves well to switch statements

I use some enum/switch combinations in the level builder I am building for my game.

EDIT: Another thing, I see you want syntax similar to;

```
if(day == Days.Saturday)
etc
```

You can do this in C++:

```
if(day == Days::Saturday)
etc
```

Here is a very simple example:

EnumAppState.h

```
#ifndef ENUMAPPSTATE_H
#define ENUMAPPSTATE_H
enum eAppState
{
    STARTUP,
    EDIT,
    ZONECREATION,
    SHUTDOWN,
    NOCHANGE
};
#endif
```

Somefile.cpp

```
#include "EnumAppState.h"
eAppState state = eAppState::STARTUP;
switch(state)
{
case STARTUP:
    //Do stuff
    break;
case EDIT:
    //Do stuff
    break;
case ZONECREATION:
    //Do stuff
    break;
case SHUTDOWN:
    //Do stuff
    break;
case NOCHANGE:
    //Do stuff
    break;
}
```

Comment: The nice thing here is that compilers will tell you if you missed putting a case in.

Comment: Shouldnt you use class enum in this case?

Comment: enum is just a datatype in C++

So declaring an enum like I did above in a .h file, and then including that file in whatever .cpp file you want to use it in will give you access to the enum. Just noticed I forgot to add the #include in my .cpp example. Editing.

Comment: Also, I see someone else saying that enums in C++ are global. In my experience, using enums the way I have above, I can only access them when I have included the .h. So this seems to stop global access too, which is always good.

EDIT: It seems like I am unknowingly using enums in a C++11 way if I am reading things right...

Answer (score 10):

If you are still using C++03 and want to use enums, you should be using enums inside a namespace. 
Eg:

```
namespace Daysofweek{
enum Days {Saturday, Sunday, Tuesday,Wednesday, Thursday, Friday};
}
```

You can use the enum outside the namespace like,

```
Daysofweek::Days day = Daysofweek::Saturday;

if (day == Daysofweek::Saturday)
{
    std::cout<<"Ok its Saturday";
}
```

Answer (score 7):

This should not work in C++:

```
Days.Saturday
```

Days is not a scope or object that contains members you can access with the dot operator. This syntax is just a C#-ism and is not legal in C++.

Microsoft has long maintained a C++ extension that allows you to access the identifiers using the scope operator:

```
enum E { A, B, C };

A;
E::B; // works with Microsoft's extension
```

But this is non-standard before C++11. In C++03 the identifiers declared in an enum exist only in the same scope as the enum type itself.

```
A;
E::B; // error in C++03
```

C++11 makes it legal to qualify enum identifiers with the enum name, and also introduces enum classes, which create a new scope for the identifiers instead of placing them in the surrounding scope.

```
A;
E::B; // legal in C++11

enum class F { A, B, C };

A; // error
F::B;
```

Answer (score 5):

Sadly, elements of the enum are 'global'. You access them by doing `day = Saturday`. That means that you cannot have `enum A { a, b } ;` and `enum B { b, a } ;` for they are in conflict.

Comment: Until you use `enum class` in C++11, that is. Before that, you have to make dummy classes.

Comment: Don't know C++11. I am assuming the question refers to C++. Yes, using classes or namespaces will do the trick.

Comment: @Grzegorz: i think chris is referring to the newly introduced enum class which provides strongly typed enums.

Comment: @Hossein: Thank you for pointing it out. I have found explanation of the num class, and I know what Chris was talking about. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Grzegorz:I didn't mean to disrespect,just thought i might be helping,sorry for any probable misunderstanding.I again Thank you for your time and helping me ;)

Comment: @Hossein: Dear Hossein - I think we are lost in translation here. I really, really thank you for pointing it to me what Chris was trying to tell me. I did not understand it and when you wrote to me, I have googled it on the Internet to learn more about this enum class. I like what I found, and all thanks go to Chris and to you. Blessings.

Answer (score 4):

While C++ (excluding C++11) has enums, the values in them are "leaked" into the global namespace.
If you don't want to have them leaked (and don't NEED to use the enum type), consider the following:

```
class EnumName {  
   public:   
      static int EnumVal1;  
      (more definitions)  
};  
EnumName::EnumVal1 = {value};  
if ([your value] == EnumName::EnumVal1)  ...
```

Answer (score 3):

Enums in C++ are like integers masked by the names you give them, when you declare your enum-values (this is not a definition only a hint how it works).

But there are two errors in your code:

1. Spell `enum` all lower case
2. You don't need the `Days.` before Saturday.
3. If this enum is declared in a class, then use
   `if (day == YourClass::Saturday){}`

Comment: The OP changed the spelling/case 16 minutes after the initial post ([revision 1](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/12183008/1) to [revision 2](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/12183008/2)).

Answer (score 1):

I think your root issue is the use of `.` instead of `::`, which will use the namespace.

Try:

```
enum Days {Saturday, Sunday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday, Friday};
Days day = Days::Saturday;
if(Days::Saturday == day)  // I like literals before variables :)
{
    std::cout<<"Ok its Saturday";
}
```

Comment: This does not work: to use the `Days::` scope as in your example, you must define the enumeration with `enum class Days` and use C++03+Microsoft extension or C++11.

Comment: @Futal, the above ran with Borland C++ Builder. Flavor / Version of C++ is not in the question.

Comment: your version of Borland C++ Builder must be using C++11 or newer. Gcc and Clang both gives errors or warnings if your example is compiled with `-std=c++98` or `-std=c++03`. Clang is quite clear: `warning: use of enumeration in a nested name specifier is a C++11 extension`.

Answer (score 1):

If we want the strict type safety and scoped enum, using `enum class` is good in C++11.

If we had to work in C++98, we can using the advice given by `InitializeSahib`,`San` to enable the scoped enum.

If we also want the strict type safety, the follow code can implement somthing like `enum`.

```
#include <iostream>
class Color
{
public:
    static Color RED()
    {
        return Color(0);
    }
    static Color BLUE()
    {
        return Color(1);
    }
    bool operator==(const Color &rhs) const
    {
        return this->value == rhs.value;
    }
    bool operator!=(const Color &rhs) const
    {
        return !(*this == rhs);
    }

private:
    explicit Color(int value_) : value(value_) {}
    int value;
};

int main()
{
    Color color = Color::RED();
    if (color == Color::RED())
    {
        std::cout << "red" << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The code is modified from the class Month example in book Effective C++ 3rd: Item 18

Answer (score 0):

Don't think of an enum as a group of objects, think of it as an integer where each numeric value has a name so `enum Days` would be better declared as `enum Day`.
If you want to contain it within a named structure put `enum Day` within a `struct Days` like this:

```
struct Days{
    enum Day{
        Saturday,
        Sunday,
        Tuesday,
        Wednesday,
        Thursday,
        Friday
    };
};
```

Then you would address them like this `Days::Saturday` and the type would be `Days::Day`

Answer (score -15):

First of all, make 'E' in enum, 'e' as a lower case.

Second, drop type name 'Days' in 'Days.Saturday'.

Third ...buy yourself a good C++ book.

Comment: Sorry you got all these down-votes (I mean, the answer does kind of deserve it), but that doesn't mean you have to leave the community for 6 years. Come back and join us. You have something to contribute too. Be helpful. Share knowledge.