# Syntax accessing Enum from parent class

Tags: c++, enums

I am getting an error with a program. Evidently I'm missing something about the syntax. The snippet of C++ code below is the smallest which produces the error.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Parent
{
    public:
    enum MyEnum {
        Value1,
        Value2,
        Value3
    };

    MyEnum* set;
};

class Child: public Parent
{
    public:
    Child()
    {
      set = new MyEnum[5];
      set[0]=MyEnum.Value1;//<--Something wrong here
      set[1]=MyEnum.Value2;//<--Something wrong here
      set[2]=MyEnum.Value3;//<--Something wrong here
      set[3]=MyEnum.Value2;//<--Something wrong here
      set[4]=MyEnum.Value1;//<--Something wrong here
    }

    void Write()
    {
        for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
        {
            cout<< "This is " << i << ": " << set[i];
        }
    }
};

int main() {
    Child c;
    c.Write();

    return 0;
}
```

The error has something to do with the indicated syntax.

```
 expected primary-expression before ‘.’ token
```

I have tried Parent.MyEnum.Value1, Parent::MyEnum.Value1, etc. nothing seems to be right. How should I be referring to the specific values in the parent class?

Comment: `MyEnum.Value1;//<--Something wrong here` - The syntax. It's just `Value1` if you have a regular enum. [Pick a good book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list), it will tell you that and more.

Comment: What is it about people that they like to assume someone is a novice or ill read because they have a question. Like I don't have three C++ books an arm's reach away. Thanks for that. Getting back to the question, WHY is that syntax acceptable? And what exactly is a "regular enum"? Is there a different kind of enum?

Comment: What, your 3 books didn't tell you about scoped and unscoped enumerations?

Comment: Ever try to search for a word you don't know? Like what do you call that thing in the back of your throat. So much book, so little search ability. But thank you for the terminology.

Comment: Well, a book may not be searchable, [but the internet is](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/enum)(First hit on Google, you can check). You asked why I assume you are a novice? Because you've made a basic syntax error, and didn't search **online** for the correct usage of the construct you misused. That's a novice mistake. So you can save you indignation, my comments were not entirely unwarranted.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use enums in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12183008/how-to-use-enums-in-c)

Comment: no, it's not "the smallest which produces the error"

Comment: @StoryTeller Not searching online cannot be fixed by buying a book.

Comment: @Gruffalo No, but it could easily be the smallest that the OP found which produces the error. This isn’t code golf; a minimal example does not need to be literally minimal. The example is small enough to be easily understood, which is the point.

Comment: @DanielH: this is a good example of how little time OP spent minimising the code, just look at `set[1-4]`. Or looking for many existing answers to similar basic C++ syntax question.

Answer (score 3):

Enums don't require qualification for their values, meaning you should access them like this:

```
set[0] = Parent::Value1;
```

If you would like to enforce qualification, you can use **strongly typed enums**. It looks like this:

```
enum struct MyEnum {
    Value1,
    Value2,
    Value3
};

set[0] = Parent::MyEnum::Value1;
```

But then you should print them using an explicit cast, e.g:

```
cout << static_cast<int>(set[0]) << endl;
```

Answer (score 1):

An `enum`, like a `class`, defines a scope. A regular enum like you use puts its enumerator names both in its own scope and its containing scope. **Since this is scope resolution, not member access, you use `::` instead of `.`**. Therefore, you can use `Parent::Value1`, `Value1` (because `public` and `protected` names of `Parent` are visible in `Child`), or `Parent::MyEnum::Value1` or `MyEnum::Value1`.

If you want to disallow the first or two options, you should use `enum class` instead of just `enum`.

Comment: Only scoped enumerations define a scope. That's why they were added to the language. For unscoped enumerations `MyEnum::Value1` only works as an extension on MSVC.

Comment: @StoryTeller I haven’t found anything allowing it, but it [works in gcc](https://godbolt.org/g/3jtSkC) and [clang](https://godbolt.org/g/x1QukD) with `-std=c++11 -Wall -Wextra -pedantic`. If you don’t include the `-std` flag, `clang` says it’s from C++11.

Comment: @StoryTeller According to a code comment in the last example [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/enum#Unscoped_enumeration), this works. I haven’t looked at the standard yet, but it matches my what the compilers say so I tentatively believe it.

Comment: Funny fact. It was changed from C++03 to C++11, when only MSVC did indeed support it as an extension. I had my standards confused. Have a +1.